# Firefox won't render fonts

Tags: html, firefox, css, font-face

So firefox doesn't want to load my fonts, the path is right I also so the request in Firebug, but it won't render it. On other browser it works perfect, here is my code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Gill Sans';
src: url('/fonts/gillsansstd-webfont.eot');
src: local('☺'), url('/fonts/gillsansstd-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/gillsansstd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/gillsansstd-webfont.svg#webfontCBlAmwSC') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I'm using wordpress and site address is set to ***www***.site.com si i've read that on www. sites firefox won't render the fonts or something like that.Do you know a solution or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved when you link the css file just do /path/to_the_file

Comment: What a stupid simple solution for something that I've spent hours trying to figure out. Upvotes for you!

Answer (score 1):

For some people, probably not your case because you solved it already, if the font extension is correct the problem could be on the MIME type extension, if you are using IIS be sure to tell him the MIME type or you are gonna face a nice 404